# Exclude GND trace from GND groundplane in Eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, grounding

I have a board layout in Eagle with a groundplane. Now I have a trace inside of this groundplane which is also GND but this one shouldn't merged into the groundplane.

The reason is, that i want to connect a decoupling capacitor to an ic and the groundlead from the capacitor to the ic should be separate from the groundplane.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really help to have a picture of your layout to evaluate if what you want to do makes sense.

Some ways to achieve what you want

- Use the Restrict layer to prevent the GND polygon from filling the area where you trace is routed.
- Separate your GND signal with a 0-Ohm resistor or some other placeholder. Eagle will obviously treat this as an independent signal (GND2 for example), not connecting it to GND.
- Just route your GND signal on another layer.